# uniquely Id a function in lua

Tags: lua

I use Lua in a game engine. I often need to do things at a given interval and the brute force way would be to make a variable for each thing I need to do to track the last time I did it. This clutters my code with variables that I don't want to see since they are more work oriented than intent oriented. So I had an idea to make a function that would do this automatically for me. All I need to provide is the interval, and a function that I define inline of what I need to be done at this interval. (in my example I use "classes" so I also define the object).

Of course I still need to make last update variables to track each one but if I can mask that inside this function then the code I have to write to use it just becomes simpler. So on my passed in obj I'm needing to make a unique variable for each statement of when I call the function. I was thinking I could use the string name of the callback function but that's different each time because it's an anonymous function. **Is there anyway from the anonymous function that I can generate a unique variable name so I don't have to track anything when using this system? Since no 2 anonymous functions for the same object would be the same some kind of hashing of the function itself maybe? Not sure if you can do that in Lua though**

```
function DoEvery(interval, obj, method)
   -- somehow I need a way to uniquely ID the passed in method so I can make a variable on the passed in obj that tracks it's last time called
   print(tostring(method)) -- this gives a new address each cycle so that won't work
end

Script = {}

function Script:Create()
   local obj = {}

   obj.name = "Mike"

   for k,v in pairs(Script) do
      obj[k] = v
   end

   return obj
end

function Script:Update()
   DoEvery(250, self, function(self)
      print(self.name)
   end)
end


local script = Script:Create()

script:Update()
script:Update()
script:Update()
```

Comment: Define named local function `function print_name(self) print(self.name) end` outside `Script:Update()` and use `DoEvery(250, self, print_name)` as `Script:Update()` body.  So you will have the same `method` argument in `DoEvery()` function on each invocation of `script:Update()`.  You can use either `tostring(method)` or `method` itself as a key inside `script` object to store last access time.

Comment: I want the function to be inline so as you're reading the code you don't have to go somewhere else to see what is happening. I want it to sort of be like a lambda expression.

Comment: Add one more argument - short description of your intention: `DoEvery(250, "print name", self, function(self)...end)`  This string argument will act as a comment (to simplify understanding of your code) and as a unique key.

Comment: I was thinking that but I feel that's like tracking the uniqueness manually which I want to avoid. Meaning I have to know not to use "print name" in any other different call to DoEvery() which will lead to manual mistakes. If I was going to go this route I'd just give it a number and that would act as a key to a dictionary where the value is the last update. I just don't want to do that manual tracking as it'll be error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution requires access to `debug` library and compiling sources without stripping the debug info (if your lua files are stored as precompiled bytecode).

```
function DoEvery(interval, obj, method)
   local info = debug.getinfo(method, "S")
   local id = info.linedefined..info.source
   print(id)
   -- "id" consists of line number and file name 
   -- where "method" function was defined
   -- so it is unique
   -- (unless you write two anonymous functions on the same line)
end
```

Comment: This works at https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo. I'll check it tonight in my game engine. If it works there this is brilliant and I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Game engines usually do not have access to debug library.

Comment: The game engine actually supports it! This will work perfect thanks!

Comment: "You should exert care when using this library. The functions provided here should be used exclusively for debugging and similar tasks, such as profiling. Please resist the temptation to use them as a usual programming tool: they can be very slow." from http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.9

Comment: this doesn't actually ID the function uniquely/at all if it's one of the most used cased for anonymous functions: returning them after binding upvalues. so be careful about that. it just returns a string depending on where the `function` keyword is, with no regards about how many of those functions are in memory. i'd recommend doing `tostring(method)` instead, that gives you the identifier internally used by lua, so it should be more robust when functions are "copied"/factory-returned/etc. it's also much faster than abusing the debug lib